# Android/Java: Set textview with char from index of string

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I want the user to put in characters into an edit text and upon a keyUp() would change a textview to match a certain char from a string.

If a user put in 4 characters in the edittext string, then the index of 3 of the string would be set for the textview.

The problem is that the program crashes when checking the 0th index of the string. 
This log command gives me the proper output,

```
            String thedefaultstring = "Hello Android";
            //e_question is the edit text
            int stringsum = e_question.getText().toString().length();
            System.out.println(thedefaultstring.charAt(stringsum));
```

But when I set the textview with the char, it crashes.

```
// t_debug3.setText(thedefaultstring.charAt(0)); //crashes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`setText(new String(thedefaultstring.charAt(stringSum));`

`setText` takes a `String` as an argument. Build a new `String` of only one `char` to trick it.